# Isometries of Hilbert cube

Tags: general-topology, reference-request

I'm looking for information about the isometries of the Hilbert cube: $Q= \prod_{i=1}^{\infty}[0,1]$, with the distance : $d((x_i),(y_i))= \sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{|x_i-y_i|}{2^i}$, but I have not accomplished much. Someone has good references on the subject. Thank you